# MONGODB. Error with arrayFilters: No array filter found for identifier 'elem' in path

Tags: arrays, mongodb, updates

I want to update the array of objects "profileSpheres".  If "profileSpheres.idq" is equal to "Q0800" and  "profileSpheres.ida" is equal to "A0810_001", then  "profileSpheres.ida" must be "A0800_001"

This is the [link to the playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5YFsLBh97Ky)

Example of document:

```
  {
    "_id": 0,
    "idu": "AA0092",
    "profileSpheres": [
      {
        "idq": "Q0780",
        "ida": "A0780_002",
        "value": null,
        "explain": null,
        "date": "2023-12-26T04:03:57.196Z"
      },
      {
        "idq": "Q0800",
        "ida": "A0810_001",
        "value": null,
        "explain": "encorvar la espalda mucho rato o usar mochilas pesadas ",
        "date": "2023-12-26T04:04:37.679Z"
      },
      {
        "idq": "Q0810",
        "ida": "A0810_002",
        "value": null,
        "explain": null,
        "date": "2023-12-26T04:04:37.755Z"
      },
      {
        "idq": "Q0820",
        "ida": "A0820_002",
        "value": null,
        "explain": null,
        "date": "2023-12-26T04:04:40.411Z"
      }
    ]
  }
```

And this is my code:

```
db.collection.updateMany({
  "idu": "AA0092"
},
{
  "$set": {
    "profileSpheres.$[elem].ida": "A0800_001"
  },
  "arrayFilters": [
    {
      "elem.idq": "Q0800"
    },
    {
      "elem.ida": "A0810_001"
    }
  ]
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `arrayFilters` should be outside of the update `{}`. Try this:

```
db.collection.update(
  {"idu": "AA0092"},
  {"$set": {"profileSpheres.$[elem].ida": "A0800_001"}},
  {"arrayFilters": [
    {
      "elem.idq": "Q0800",
      "elem.ida": "A0810_001"
    }
  ]}
)
```

See How it works on the [mongoDB playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lMmYcNE6t3O)